# Offset/move polygons in specific direction QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, offset

I want to offset/move the polygons in the direction north-north-western direction and perform this task 3 times. I can do this manually but it would be an approximation and I want them to exactly match. The polygons are 100m long and 5m wide, so it should be moved with 25m three times.

[image: first polygon grid]

[image: second polygon offset grid]

Comment: You can move features with the Affine Transform tool. Array of translated features may be easier for your use case, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following expression with [Geometry Generator or Geometry by expression](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814) to shift polygons. Using function [`project()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#project), you can define distance/angle, thus avoiding trigonometry. Define distance, direction (angle, azimuth) and number of times the polygons should be shifted.

*Shift polygons 3 times for 25m (25, 50 and 75 m) in NNW direction (337.5 degrees from north):*
[image]

```
collect_geometries(
    array_foreach (
        generate_series (1,3),  -- number of times the polygons are shifted
        with_variable(
            'shift',
            @element,
            make_polygon(
                make_line(
                    array_foreach(
                        generate_series (1, num_points($geometry)),
                        project( 
                            point_n(nodes_to_points($geometry), @element),
                            25*@shift,  -- distance to shift the polygons
                            radians(337.5)  -- azimuth (angle)/direction the polygons should be shifted
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can Affine transform twice, with x-axis translation -9.57 (`sin(22.5)*25`) and y-axis 23.10 (`cos(22.5)*25`)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the tool `array (of) translated features`. You may enter how many times you want to copy and move your objects, as well as the distance along X- and Y-axis. The later may require some trigonometry on your part to figure out the exact distance, but an expression as part of data-defined override might help you out there.